# JavaFX FXML Controller Communication

Tags: java, javafx

I have a question regarding transferring data through controllers using Fxml and Openjfx version 11.0.2. I have tried a few methods and none of them worked. Below is a snipped of how the most recent version is written. The alert is designed to do more than send yes/no thus I need a custom one and cannot simply use the alert already built in. The issue I am having is the buttons work but the answer value remains false even when yes is clicked where answer should update to true. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated thank you.

**EDIT Solution**
I ended up working out a solution I will update it here if anyone in the future may need a similar solution. You have to create the scene in the controller one then from that point it will behave as expected.

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import sample.Alerts;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button callAlertsButton;

    @FXML
    private void callAlerts(){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Scene2.fxml"));
            Parent root = loader.load();
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setTitle("Scene 2");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            Alerts alerts = loader.getController();
            stage.showAndWait();
            System.err.println(alerts.answer());

        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Method**

```
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("scene1.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Sample");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller One method used for calling**

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import sample.Alerts;

public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Button callAlertsButton;

    @FXML
    private void callAlerts(){
        sample.Alerts alerts = new Alerts();
        alerts.display();
        System.err.println(alerts.answer());
    }
}
```

**Controller Two being called**

```
public class Alerts {
    @FXML
    private Button yesButton;

    private boolean answer = false;
    
    public void display(){
        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Scene2.fxml"));
            Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
            stage.setTitle("Scene 2");
            stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
            stage.showAndWait();
        } catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void yesClick(){
        answer = true;
        Stage stage = (Stage) yesButton.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    public boolean answer(){
        return answer;
    }
}
```

**FXML scene1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="callAlertsButton" layoutX="167.0" layoutY="140.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#callAlerts" prefHeight="24.0" prefWidth="266.0" text="CallAlerts" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

**FXML Scene 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>


<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<Pane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Alerts">
   <children>
      <Button fx:id="yesButton" layoutX="269.0" layoutY="200.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#yesClick" text="Button" />
   </children>
</Pane>
```

Comment: Have you assigned actions `yesClick()`, `noClick` for buttons somehow?

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: You seem to be assuming the `Alerts` instance you created in your `callAlerts()` method is the controller for the FXML file. It isn't. Assuming (note how many assumptions I have to make because you didn't post a [mre]) you assigned `yesButton()` and `noButton` as event handlers for the buttons, the `answer` field will be changed in the controller, not in this `Alerts` instance.

Comment: @James_D  and kleopatra I hope that is enough information for the both of you. Also James concerning your idea with event handlers I believe you are correct that is why originally I tried to use FXMLLOADER and then load the controller but I still ended up with he same results. It's been awhile since I have used javafx, so maybe I am unfamiliar with the proper steps.

Comment: Your example would indicate you can actually still use a `Dialog<Boolean>` here. Just add the `ButtonType.YES` and `ButtonType.NO` button types to the dialog and set an appropriate result converter. If you need custom content rather than just a simple message then you can set the `content` property of the dialog to any node.

Comment: You've posted two `sample.Controller` classes. Which one are you actually using? The first looks correct. (Though I haven't had time to test; I will later.)